# Javascript HTML radio buttons - assistance with code not rendering properly in web browser

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am building the simple code with radio buttons which on click produce response "You defeated the dragon with" and then the name of the weapon.

Can someone please check the code and tell my why it does not render correctly in web server ?

Here is the code:

```
<body>
    <h1>With what weapon will you fight the dragon?</h1>
    <form action="">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="radio"   name="weapon"   id="radSpoon"   value="spoon"   checked="checked" />

            <label for="radSpoon">Spoon</label>
            <input type="radio"   name="weapon"   id="radFlower"   value="flower" />
            <label for="radSpoon">Flower</label>
            <input type="radio"   name="weapon"   id="radNoodle"   value="wet noodle" />
            <label for="radNoodle">Wet Noodle</label>

            <button type="button"   onclick="fight()">fight the dragon  </button>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    <div id="output">
    </div>
</body>
<script type = "text/javascript" >

    // from radioGroup.html  

    function fight() {
        var weapon = document.getElementsByName("weapon");
        for (i = 0; i < weapon.length; i++) {
            currentWeapon = weapon[i];
            if (currentWeapon.checked) {
                var selectedWeapon = currentWeapon.value;
            } // end if 
        } // end for 
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        var response = "<h2>You defeated the dragon with a ";
        response += selectedWeapon + "<\/h2> \n";
        output.innerHTML = response;
    } // end function
</script>
```

Functioning code as snippet:

```js
function fight() {
  var weapon = document.getElementsByName("weapon");
  for (i = 0; i < weapon.length; i++) {
    currentWeapon = weapon[i];
    if (currentWeapon.checked) {
      var selectedWeapon = currentWeapon.value;
    } // end if 
  } // end for 
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var response = "<h2>You defeated the dragon with a ";
  response += selectedWeapon + "<\/h2> \n";
  output.innerHTML = response;
} // end function
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>With what weapon will you fight the dragon?</h1>
  <form action="">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="radio"   name="weapon"   id="radSpoon"   value="spoon"   checked="checked" />
      <label for="radSpoon">Spoon</label>
      <input type="radio"   name="weapon"   id="radFlower"   value="flower" />
      <label for="radSpoon">Flower</label>
      <input type="radio"   name="weapon"   id="radNoodle"   value="wet noodle" />
      <label for="radNoodle">Wet Noodle</label>
      <button type="button"   onclick="fight()">fight the dragon  </button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div id="output">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what does not render correctly mean? for me it renders perfectly,, at least the initial render, also when you have that bunch of code put it online so that we  can see what is going on https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/eo96z3a2/3/

Comment: Zdravo Eugene! Evo link koji ne renda ispravno: http://142.93.226.239/dragonfight/dragonfight.html

Comment: Please use translated comments in English - the common language of the site.

Comment: Your question needs to be updated to clearly define the exact issue including the expected results including exactly what "why it does not render correctly" means so we can properly address your needs.

Comment: @EugenSunic - best to make JavaScript code work IN the question if possible as illustrated by using a code snipped within the question body rather than an external site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  function fight() {
    var weapon = document.getElementsByName("weapon");
    for (i = 0; i < weapon.length; i++) {
      currentWeapon = weapon[i];
      if (currentWeapon.checked) {
        var selectedWeapon = currentWeapon.value;
      } // end if 
    } // end for 
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var response = "<h2>You defeated the dragon with a ";
    response += selectedWeapon + "<\/h2> \n";
    output.innerHTML = response;
  } //


document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', ()=>{ fight()})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/eo96z3a2/5/

if you want to avoid the eventListener in the js code then do this, (should be onlick)

```
<body>
  <h1>With what weapon will you fight the dragon?</h1>
  <form action="">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="radio" name="weapon" id="radSpoon" value="spoon" checked="checked" />

      <label for="radSpoon">Spoon</label>
      <input type="radio" name="weapon" id="radFlower" value="flower" />
      <label for="radSpoon">Flower</label>
      <input type="radio" name="weapon" id="radNoodle" value="wet noodle" />
      <label for="radNoodle">Wet Noodle</label>
      <button type="button" onclick="fight()">fight the dragon </button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div id="output">
  </div>
</body>



<script>

  function fight() {
    var weapon = document.getElementsByName("weapon");
    for (i = 0; i < weapon.length; i++) {
      currentWeapon = weapon[i];
      if (currentWeapon.checked) {
        var selectedWeapon = currentWeapon.value;
      } // end if 
    } // end for 
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var response = "<h2>You defeated the dragon with a ";
    response += selectedWeapon + "<\/h2> \n";
    output.innerHTML = response;
  } //


 </script>
</html>
```